# Best performance for basic arbitrary-precision arithmetic with arbitrary base

Tags: c++, performance, math, assembly

What is the best way to perform *basic arbitrary-precision arithmetic on an arbitrary base*, with **best performance** ?

I was thinking about switching to binary, and then work with some inline assembly, but actually, I need the best-performance way to do it and I am not sure that this is the best way to do it.

EDIT : I do not want to use any library except the standart C++ one.

Comment: This is a very broad question. 1) Arbitrary precision with "best" performance is a big deal in itself. 2) Arbitrary base, makes it that much more complicated since you have to make trade-offs between if and when to change representations. 3) Using "standard C++" will never get you "best performance". I you want "best" performance, you need to get dirty - into assembly.

Comment: 1. Write some code that solves your problem. 2. Measure it. 3. Tune it.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I did not mean to use the standart library actually, this was more a way of saying that I need to make this on my own.
Arbitrary base is a part of the thing, I know this won't be easy but I am looking for great performance (assembly is what I am probably going on, if I don't find anything better).
About switching from the arbitrary base to binary, I am not sure this is the best way to do it, but I don't see a better one.

Comment: I would recommend to write a first approach in C (not in C++, because C is closer to assembly) and then see how far you can get there. Then you you can start to finetune it, by rewriting parts in assembly if needed. If you don't know assembly, you may easily write worse performant code, then the compiler generates, because using assembler is no guaruantee for fastest code. ;)

Comment: Assembly is not my best, but I've already worked with it.
I think I am going to do that way, being that I will first write it simply and then inlining assembly in the most critical parts. Thank you :)
If you know a good way to do the whole thing though, that will be good to  hear.

Comment: Probably your best bet is to get a high-performance arbitrary precision package that uses powers-of-two (32 or 64 bit "digits"; I'm sure these exist for C++) as its basic representation, and then produce numbers in the "base" (I assume you mean radix) of interest only when you print.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is, "best" performance attainable with multiprecision numeric algorithms very strongly depends on the data you're working with (such as average order of numbers you may need to calculate). Consider the discussion of algorithm selection used by gnu gmp as an example:

https://gmplib.org/manual/Algorithms.html

Gnu GMP code is also used inside glibc (in particular, in precise floating point conversion code), so in a sense it is part of a "standard c" library.

Speaking of personal experience, it is extremely difficult to beat GMP's performance figures (in fact, it is rather difficult to even get within factor of 2 to GMP's performance in a general case, so if performance is an absolute priority you may want to reconsider your design goals). Performance in multiprecision calculations is not strongly dependent on implementation technique (so you're not going to win anything by using assembly instead of something like Java for this matter, if your numbers are reasonably long) - the algorithmic complexities will necessarily dominate. In fact, it makes sense to start with highest level language available and optimize from there.

And just in case, you should definitely go through chapter 4, volume 2 of Knuth's TAoCP if you haven't done so already.

I know this is probably not the answer you're looking for, but it's longer than a comment.